# Is the Guitar Hero World Tour guitar model 95451.805 compatible with dongle 95451.806?

Tags: ps3, guitar-hero-world-tour

I got a PS3 Guitar Hero World Tour guitar model 95451.805 with no dongle and I'm trying to find which dongle would be compatible with it. I've seen on ebay the dongle model 95451.805, but it's always very expensive. I also noticed that there is a dongle 95451.806, which is cheaper and I was wondering if would be compatible with my guitar. Thank you.